# PHRETS 2.0 cannot get image

Tags: phrets

I am currently working something that need to get the data from RETS, where I can extract information from RETS but cannot get the image. I tried to use the following code:

```
$photos = $rets->GetObject("Property", "Photo", $record['L_ListingID'], "*", 1);

if ($photos !== null) {
foreach ($photos as $photo){
var_dump ($photo);
}
}
```

and receive the result below:

```
object(PHRETS\Models\Object)#71 (10) {
["content_type":protected]=>
string(8) "text/xml"
["content_id":protected]=>
string(9) "261860123"
["object_id":protected]=>
string(1) "1"
["mime_version":protected]=>
NULL
["location":protected]=>
NULL
["content_description":protected]=>
NULL
["content_sub_description":protected]=>
NULL
["content":protected]=>
string(71) "
"
["preferred":protected]=>
NULL
["error":protected]=>
object(PHRETS\Models\RETSError)#73 (2) {
["code":protected]=>
int(0)
["message":protected]=>
string(0) ""
}
}
```

as the code suggested, I can only get "text/xml" returned as the content_type of the object, where I should be expecting a jpg file. How can I get the image and not get the text as a result?

Answer (score 0):

If you can get the MLS number, this will help you out.

```
$photo = $rets->GetObject('Property', 'Photo', $mls, 1, 1);
```

$mls is the mls number, the first '1' gets you the first image, and the second 1 will get you the URL. If you want the actual image to download, the second '1' will need to be '0'. If you make the first '1' a '*' then you'll get all of the images for that MLS.

Comment: The "MLS number" Tom is referring to is the Property Key Field, usually the one with a SystemName of `ListingID`.

Answer (score -1):

To test take a known mls number from you mls and enter it as shown below.

Get the url of all images can be as many as 100+
$photos = $rets->GetObject("Property", "Photo", 123456789, "*", 1);

Get url of 1st image
$photos = $rets->GetObject("Property", "Photo", 123456789, "1", 1);

Get url of 5th image
$photos = $rets->GetObject("Property", "Photo", 123456789, "5", 1);

---

Get all physical images can be as many as 100+
$photos = $rets->GetObject("Property", "Photo", 123456789, "*", 0);

Get 1st physical image
$photos = $rets->GetObject("Property", "Photo", 123456789, "1", 1);

Get 5th physical image
$photos = $rets->GetObject("Property", "Photo", 123456789, "5", 1);

Then you must store the image URLs in a data base and if you are getting actual images you must store them in a directory.

If you had provided more info on $record['L_ListingID'], how you got this I would be able to tell you if it contained the MLS number as it must to be able to do what you are trying to do...